# compare information stored in a cookie to that of a PHP variable

Tags: php, variables, cookies

I am trying to work on a way of comparing the date + time in a cookie to that of variable date and time that is pulled from a database.

Example:

i set a cookie when a page is viewed e.g cookie name, $date + time

i then also have a variable e.g.

```
$lastupdate = 'time of update'
```

How do i go about comparing the date + time of the cookie stored, of that of the php variable e.g.

```
$lastupdate
```

So i basicly want to do

```
if $cookie time date > $lastupdate
```

Ignore the variable names etc its just for placeholders and examples :)

Craig

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Getting the time from the database? Getting the time from the cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get time from your cookie:

```
$time = $_COOKIE['get date & time value'];
```

Get last update from database

```
$lastupdate = "date & Time from database";
```

And try this

```
$t1 = strtotime($time);
$t2 = strtotime($lastupdate);

if($t1 != $t2) {  //operator can be >, < , <=, >=, !, !=
  //do something
 }else{
 //do something else
}
```

Comment: just needed the first part really.

Wasnt sure on getting the value out but now its been said it makes sense :) Always the way.

what about getting the data from a certain cookie name?

So i have e.g. $setcookie("cookiename", "dateandtime");

How do i pull from just that one?

Answer (score 0):

You could transform them in seconds with format('U') and then compare them.

See http://php.net/manual/it/datetime.format.php